# New Tenancy 1.x Laravel How Insert Data after create DB

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I am trying to test the new version of Tenancy 1.X in laravel, but I don't understand how to insert data after creating a Tenant database

I mean in the same function

I understand that the function in charge of creating is:

```
Created :: class,
```

Someone use this version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on that now with no less issues and unknownledge but step by step I'm resolve my requirements. What exactly are you trying to do? Insert data from tenant domain or from another, for example main app.

main app:

- Tenancy::setTenant($tenant)
- App\Modals\Tenant\User::create(....);
- App\Modals\Tenant\User::update(....);